# How do I reference a React component in a regular HTML page

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created a React application with an index.html that looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html!>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="react-container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.html references index.js (from bundle.js) which calls ReactDOM.render to render the app, like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import App from './components/App'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './redux/configureStore'

render(
    <Provider store={configureStore()}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

So far so good. But I want my component to be reusable in other web applications. So what do I need to do?

I guess I would not provide an index.html or index.js file in the bundle? But how should I reference the component in the other web application? I guess that I need to reference the bundle.js file, but how to I for example specify imports? And what about Babel? And the React libraries?

As I am also utilizing Redux, I need a Provider, and I need to configure a store. Where should I do that?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your question is actually pretty broad and requires a number of different steps, and some can require different techniques to do so. I would start here https://medium.com/@lokhmakov/best-way-to-create-npm-packages-with-create-react-app-b24dd449c354 . as far as redux I would look at what other redux component packages do like https://github.com/kuy/redux-tooltip good luck and feel free to come back if you have more specific question

Comment: Why don't you have a look at one of the many react libraries on github and see how they do it?

Comment: To try to simplify my question: I have created a React application with one component, and I want to add it into my non-React web portal. What is the easiest way to accomplish that?

Answer (score -2):

To be able to reuse the component you need to build it to export a render function. I think nwb would be a good fit for you https://github.com/insin/nwb/blob/master/docs/guides/ReactComponents.md#developing-react-components-and-libraries-with-nwb
This way you can build a UMD module that exports a global variable to use with your script tag and / or publish that to npm

Instead of rendering it explicitly using ReactDOM, I would rather make the index.js export a component instead.
eg:

```
export default props =>
   <Provider store={configureStore()}>
      <App />
   </Provider>
```

And let the user code render it to the dom

```
 ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(YourLibraryGlobalNameGeneratedFromNwb))
```